# Trying to send HTML form field value in JSON POST call to API but getting syntax err showing that whole HTML page code is being sent as JSON

Tags: javascript, django, single-page-application

I am building a Single Page App using Django and JavaScript.

In Django app in the views.py I have the following function acting as add-post API endpoint:

```
def post_add(request):
    '''
    API endpoint for creating a new post
    '''
    # save data submitted by the user
    if request.method != "POST":
        return JsonResponse({"error": "POST request required."}, status=400)

    else:
        form = PostForm(request.POST)

        # check if form is valid server-side
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False) # save without commit as we have to associate some variables that were not in the form
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()

            return JsonResponse({"message": "Post added successfully."}, status=201)
        else:
            # return JsonResponse({"message": "Errors in the form."}, status=400)
```

In JavaScript I have added event listener after the whole document has been loaded and within it an event listener on the submit button that removes the default submit action and triggers my add_post() function:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // add function call on add post form submission
  document.querySelector("#create-post").addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancels default form submission action on clicking the submit button in the form
    add_post();
  });
});
```

And here is the add_post() function in JavaScript that sends data for the new post (1 field in the form) and calls the API endpoint:

```
function add_post() {
    // add post from the form to DB
    console.log("add_post called")
    fetch('/add-post', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            content: document.querySelector("#post-content").value,
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data)
    {console.log(data)
    })
    // catch any errors and log them into console
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error:', error)
    });
}
```

When trying to submit my new post form I am getting the following error in the browser console (and no error from Django, just *"POST /add-post HTTP/1.1" 200 1885*

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "

<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

That would suggest that as the JSON the whole HTML document with the form is being sent.

I have checked in the console, and `document.querySelector("#post-content").value` used in my JS function sending the data to the API is properly selecting only the value of the expected form field.

What else could be wrong? Why I am seeing whole HTML in the error return by the fetch method in add_post() JS function?